# Ajax wait for the request page to be fully loaded and generated

Tags: javascript, ajax, url, get

I need to get data from page A to page B (current page) with ajax.
In page A, some elements are generated by javascript with the id given in the url.

Is there any way to wait for those elements to be generated ? Because in the response, I don't get them.

```
$.get({
    url: 'http://example.com/?id=abcd1234',
    success: function(response){
        console.log(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: the implementation of the waiting will be in page A, after the elements generated you can send the response from page A to page B.

Comment: I can't do anything on page A ...

Comment: the problem in page A they reply to page B before generating elements, so i don't know away to to stop page A from replying through the request of page B.